# How can you send a transaction directly to the memory pool?

Tags: transactions, mempool, validation

Is it possible to send a transaction to the bitcoin memory pool directly to have it mined without validating it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such thing as "the bitcoin memory pool". Every node has its own memory pool; it is not shared across all nodes in the network. A node can certainly add a transaction to its own mempool without validating it, but you cannot force other nodes to add a transaction to its mempool without validation. In fact, you can't force a node to add a transaction to its mempool, nor can you force a node to accept anything.